# Joomla Module Positions Not Showing Up in Backend

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Hello I have Joomla setup on localhost, and I am using a custom template. I have a templateDetails file which has my positions defined in it. In my index.php, i include the module using:

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="custom_mod" />`.

Now when I try to create a new module, such as a login form, I don't see the module position in the backend (there is a drop down menu with all the positions available).  In fact I don't see ANY positions for my template.  But `<jdoc:include type="content" />` works perfectly fine.

Also I went into Template Manager and enabled "Preview Positions" and it does show 'custom_mod'.

I am using Joomla 3.2.

Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Preview positions is based on your index.php file. The positions list is based on templateDetails.xml. So I would say you may have a problem in your xml causing it not to be read.

Comment: You're missing a double quote after the name. Change `name="custom_mod` to `name="custom_mod"`

Answer (score 1):

Even though your custom position(s) arent showing up in the dropdown, that does not mean they are not there. You can manually type in the name of the position and press enter. It should then show your module in the correct spot. After having done so, it will be added to the list of positions you have manually defined (at the end of the dropdown menu) so the next time you make a module and put it in that position, it should appear as usual. It will also then appear in the filter-modules-by-position dropdown.

I am currently trying to figure out where the filter function gets its data from, and will update my answer as soon as i figure it out completely. For now, just type it in manually!